# How to position a container inside a column in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am newbie in flutter, I am trying to move my RaisedButton Widget to bottom left portion of screen. I tried almost every existing solution on stackoverflow but none of them worked!!

[image]

Above is the screenshot of where I want to place my button

and here is my code,

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black87,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "${divStuff()}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 120.0,
                  fontFamily:
                      'PIXymbols', //PIXymbols Digit Clocks W90 Bd from onlinewebfonts.com
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            Container(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _launchURL,
                child: new Text('Learn More'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the column widget and use Stack and center the main widget, then position the rest by using Align widgets.

```
Material(
    color: Colors.black87,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              "${divStuff()}",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 120.0,
                fontFamily: 'PIXymbols',
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: new Text('Learn More'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Align widget like so :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black87,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          Text(
                "${divStuff()}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 120.0,
                  fontFamily:
                      'PIXymbols', //PIXymbols Digit Clocks W90 Bd from onlinewebfonts.com
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            Align( //The align widget
            alignment : Alignment.bottomLeft, 
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _launchURL,
                child: new Text('Learn More'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code? If so, I guess you'll need to fix the brackets because I just demonstrated how to use the align widget. The Align widget takes two args namely the alignment and child property.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end property of a column?

```
Column(
minAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end
child:Container()
)
```

Comment: changing the mainAxisAlignment would make it so that all widgets are aligned in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **Stack** widget for this type of usecase.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black87,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "${divStuff()}",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 120.0,
                fontFamily:
                'PIXymbols', //PIXymbols Digit Clocks W90 Bd from onlinewebfonts.com
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: new Text('Learn More'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:Home()));
}
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('demo')),
      body: Material(
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "1000",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 120.0,
                      fontFamily:
                      'PIXymbols', //PIXymbols Digit Clocks W90 Bd from onlinewebfonts.com
                    ),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed:(){},
                  child: new Text('Learn More'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @ojha100 just add expanded and align widget